# What's the best way to change the size of a list in Dart?

Tags: list, dart

- I have a list with `oldLength` items.
- I want it to have `newLength` items.
- If `newLength < oldLength`, I just want to cut the extra items.
- If `newLength > oldLength`, I want to fill it with nulls.

I wrote this:

```
List<T> cutList<T>(List<T> oldList, int newLength) {
    return new List.generate(newLength, (index) {
      if (index < oldList.length) return oldList[index];
      else return null;
   });
}
```

Is there a better way, in terms of simplicity? And in terms of efficiency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a growable list and you don't mind mutating it:

```dart
List<T?> cutList<T>(List<T?> oldList, int newLength) {
  oldList.length = newLength;
  return oldList;
}
```

Notice that after Dart introduced Null Safety, you can only *grow* a list like this if its element type is nullable (because otherwise it can't assign `null` to the new element positions). Since you ask to grow with `null` values, that should be the case.
The declaration of `cutList` here ensures that the list type is nullable.

If you want to create a new list, then you still need to know that `T` is nullable (otherwise you can't create a larger list):

```dart
List<T?> cutList<T>(List<T?> oldList, int newLength) {
  return List<T?>.filled(newLength, null)
    ..setRange(0, min(newLength, oldList.length), oldList);
}
```

(where `min` is imported from `dart:math`).

For a more modern-Dart approach, I'd probably go with:

```dart
List<T?> cutList<T>(List<T?> oldList, int newLength) {
    return <T?>[...oldList.take(newLength), 
                for (var i = oldList.length; i < newLength; i++) null];
```

There are so many ways. Anything that only copies each element once is good.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Above but It's an extension so you can use it on any List anytime you want

### Without Math Library

```dart
extension CutList<T> on List<T?> {
  List<T?> cutList(List<T?> oldList, int newLength) {
    return <T?>[
      ...oldList.take(newLength),
      for (var i = oldList.length; i < newLength; i++) null
    ];
  }
}
```

### With Math

```dart
import 'dart:math';

extension CutList<T> on List<T?> {
  List<T?> cutList(List<T?> oldList, int newLength) {
    return List<T?>.filled(newLength, null)
      ..setRange(0, min(newLength, oldList.length), oldList);
  }
}
```